# Writing Data Structures to files using FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

I have an android application and want to store/retrieve to memory a data structure that I created on the onPause()/onResume() methods so that the data will persist between runs via FileOutputStream/FileInputStream, which is the standard practice for this.

So, how do I save a data structure to a file so that I can obtain it later (I've seen examples of doing it with Strings but not other objects)? Am I forced to create a getBytes() function for my data structure and the subsequent objects which it contains in addition to making constructors for all of these objects that creates them from byte arrays?

Edit: Ah, okay; so this is called serialization.
Is the the following correct?

To write:

```
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("filename");
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
out.writeObject(e);
out.close();
fileOut.close();
```

To read:

```
FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("filename");
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
e = (ObjectType) in.readObject();
in.close();
fileIn.close();
```

Edit2: Also, the data structure and contained objects (and sub-objects) should all implement Serializable.
So for instance, if I had a BST of ArrayLists of Dogs then I would make the BST, ArrayList, and Dog classes all implement Serializable and then call the functions above.

Is all of this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the Serializable library [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html). This allows you to write a class directly down to a non-human readable file, then can be read back in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Can you confirm the information in my edits? :)

Comment: Edit1: Yes, that is how you can save and load externally from the class.

Edit2: The Sub-objects may or may not have to implement Serializable. I haven't used it lately so I'm a bit rusty, but I'm sure that you'll be able to find it in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! For those who were wondering, the documentation says that only serializable types that aren't flagged with "transient" will be serialized. Primative types are serializable by default but Objects must implement Serializable to be saved. Therefore, for an object to be truly recreated, all of its subobjects must implement Serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Its common to serialize your data with JSON or XML.  Otherwise, you could look into google protocol buffers for a more densely packed data file.